# Stacking a dataset

Tags: sas, data-manipulation

What's the code program in SAS to stack data?
For the purpose of example, lets say I have this dataset:

```
DATA test.one;
INPUT Name $ Y1996 Y1997 Y1998 Y1999;
cards;
Dan 5 10 40 20
Derek 10 12 10 10
run;

proc print data = test.one;
run;
```

Running this set would give me an output like this:

```
Name     Y1996   Y1997  Y1998  Y1999
Dan       5      10     40     20
Derek     10     12     10     10
```

However, I would want my data to look like this:

```
Name   Year  Income
Dan    1996    5
Dan    1997    10
Dan    1998    40
Dan    1999    20
Derek  1996    10
Derek  1997    12
Derek  1998    10
Derek  1999    10
```

It would create a new variable income corresponding to the stacking the of the data as shown above.

Comment: This is more commonly known as a transpose, and use PROC TRANSPOSE for it :)

Comment: Thank you, ill just post an answer which I found thanks to your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to read the raw data directly into that form?

```
DATA want;
   INPUT Name $ @;
   do year=1996 to 1999;
     input income @;
     output;
   end;
cards;
Dan 5 10 40 20
Derek 10 12 10 10
;
```

Answer (score 0):

The PROC Transpose can solve this;

```
DATA test.one;
INPUT Name $ y1996 y1997 y1998 y1999;
cards;
Dan 5 10 40 20
Derek 10 12 10 10
run;

proc print data = test.one;
run;

proc transpose data=test.one out=long1;
by name;
run;

data test2;
set long1 (rename=(col1=Income));
RUN;
```

It will then transform the dataset into a stacked version.

Comment: You can do the rename in proc transpose - or look into prefix, as well as id/idlabel statements.